# Cant't find content of Python37-32\Scripts on path while path is configured

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, pip, system-paths

I cant access contents of "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\Scripts" on the commandline but i have configured it as a user path.

When i installed a Python package using Pip i got an warning message that the install location of the package was not on my PATH.
So i added C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\Scripts as a path under the name PythonScripts.

```
WARNING: The script f2py.exe is installed in 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
```

When i try to run a file located in the Python37-32\Scripts folder like pip.exe i an error that the program is not found.

```
pip.exe : The term 'pip.exe' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Che
ck the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ pip.exe
+ ~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (pip.exe:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Comment: What do you mean saying *"added … as a path under the name PythonScripts"*? `PATH` entries don't have names.

Comment: Check `$env:path.split(';')` in PowerShell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be a number of issues.

> F2PY uses numpy_distutils that supports a number of Fortran 77/90/95 compilers

Because the library is a **Fortran compiler**, it probably does not like directory names that are longer than 8 characters or has symbols and spaces.  Try installing to a simpler directory.

```
# Instead of this:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\Scripts

# Replace with this:
C:\python37\Scripts
```

Next, try using the full numpy utility.  Generally packages are stored in:

```
C:\...\python\Lib\site-packages  on Windows directory.
```

Make sure you have numpy installed there, and install f2.py where numpy_distutils is in the folder structure.

Then add environment path to

```
C:\python37\
C:\python37\Scripts\
C:\python37\Lib\
C:\python37\site-packages
```

Hopefully that will do it.

Comment: I installed Python in C:\Python and now the paths work!

Comment: Hi woldgrep, that was wonderful!  Thanks for the points too.  Jennifer